# Import csv files to hbase

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, hbase

I want fill mytable:Province in hbase using csv file. To do this, I used the following command:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.importtsv -Dimport.columns=
HBASE_ROW_KEY,ProvinceINFO:ID, ProvinceINFO:Name Province /usr/data/province.csv
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase
/mapreduce
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce. Program will exit.
```

So, to solve this I did the following:

copy hbase.site.xml to hadoop/conf

copy all hbase jar files  and zookeeper.jar and guava.jar into hadoop/lib

and set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`  and `HBASE_pATH` as you can see in following:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/Desktop  
/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.95.0-
hadoop2-tests.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-examples-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/Desktop/hbase
/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-
0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-it-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/Desktop/hbase
/lib/hbase-it-0.95.0-hadoop2-tests.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-0.95.0-
hadoop2.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:$/Desktop/hbase
/lib/hbase-server-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:$/Desktop/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.95.0-hadoop2-
tests.jar:/Desktop/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/Desktop/hbase/conf:/Desktop/hbase
/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.
```

But it does not change.

Please guide me

Comment: The class name should be `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv`

Comment: how i can get it and add?

Comment: What zsxwing means I think is change `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.importtsv` to `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv` in the command you are using.

Comment: tnx. it is corrected.but now error me: ERROR: No columns specified. Please specify with -Dimporttsv.columns=...
before i create my table in hbase like this: create 'Province', 'ProvinceINFO'